# Constructing an SQL statement that determines which columns to show based on row values of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I am trying to understand how to do this procedure..

Basically,

I have table 1 -> 90+ columns

I have table 2 -> has a column called attributes, which has rows that correspond to one of the 90+ columns of table 1

What I want to do is show table 1 ONLY with the columns that are in table 2's rows.

SELECT [table 2 row values ] FROM table 1

How would I go about doing this? Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for something like `select * from table_1 where table_1.attribute in (select attribute from table_2)`?

Comment: More like (SELECT [ROW VALUES FROM SELECT * FROM TABLE2] FROM TABLE 1)

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Are you trying to select **columns** in table1 based on **rows** in table2?  As in some sort of dynamic sql?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see the JOIN clause [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

It may be helpful for your question.